# Should a Google Business page for an international business be created for SEO?

Tags: google, google-search

When building a website for an international business,  is it an SEO problem if you don't create a Google Business page?

I have read many articles that say that a business page is necessary for SEO.
Is there a need to create a Google Business page?  Is it harmful to SEO not to have one?

On the other hand, I have seen some websites that seem to be doing good business without creating Google Business page.

Comment: What type of business is it?   It isn't very useful to create a Google Business Page for an online-only business.   If the business has a storefront or local service area though, it should have business page.

Comment: The business is online content base like health or sports articles.

Comment: Unless it has a local presence (off-line) I don't think a business listing helps in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Google Business page does help in improving your website ranking in search results. By having a GB page, Google will be able to verify your business and will display your website in Google Maps and search results. Your posts in GB will be indexed in Google and people can be able give review on your page so that it will be displayed for other users as well.

Conclusion: Having a verified Google business page will do help your users to find you business, business location, office timings and reviews by given by other users. It also helps your website reachable to your users.